# How can I add child objects to a PsObject?

Tags: powershell, object, psobject, add-member

Is this the correct way to have a PsObject as a Property of a parent PsObject?

This seems somewhat cumbersome to be the correct way and I can't dot source (see pictures at the bottom) the child PsObject's properties either.

> $function1.Params | fl
>
> InformationAction   : @{InformationAction=IA1; Name=InformationAction;
> ParameterType=System.String; ParameterSets={[__AllParameterSets,
> System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}; IsDynamic=False;
> Aliases=ia; Attributes=; SwitchParameter=False}
>
> WarningAction       : @{WarningAction=IA1; Name=WarningAction; ParameterType=System.String;
> ParameterSets={[__AllParameterSets,
> System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]};
> IsDynamic=False; Aliases=ia; Attributes=; SwitchParameter=False}
>
> ErrorAction         : @{ErrorAction=IA1;
> Name=ErrorAction; ParameterType=System.String;
> ParameterSets={[__AllParameterSets,
> System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]};
> IsDynamic=False; Aliases=ia; Attributes=; SwitchParameter=False}
>
> InformationVariable :
> @{InformationVariable=IA1; Name=InformationVariable;
> ParameterType=System.String; ParameterSets={[__AllParameterSets,
> System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}; IsDynamic=False;
> Aliases=ia; Attributes=; SwitchParameter=False}
>
> WarningVariable     : @{WarningVariable=IA1; Name=WarningVariable;
> ParameterType=System.String; ParameterSets={[__AllParameterSets,
> System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}; IsDynamic=False;
> Aliases=ia; Attributes=; SwitchParameter=False}
>
> ErrorVariable       : @{ErrorVariable=IA1; Name=ErrorVariable; ParameterType=System.String;
> ParameterSets={[__AllParameterSets,
> System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]};
> IsDynamic=False; Aliases=ia; Attributes=; SwitchParameter=False}

Here is a code snippet to duplicate what I am doing.

```
#Region Step 1 (create object)

    $function1 = New-Object PsObject;
    $function1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "Test1";
    $function1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Params" -NotePropertyValue $null;

    $param1 = New-Object PsObject;
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "InformationAction" -NotePropertyValue "IA1";
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "InformationAction";
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterType" -NotePropertyValue "System.String";
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterSets" -NotePropertyValue "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}";
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "IsDynamic" -NotePropertyValue "False";
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Aliases" -NotePropertyValue "ia";
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Attributes" -NotePropertyValue $null;
    $param1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SwitchParameter" -NotePropertyValue "False";

    $param2 = New-Object PsObject;
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "WarningAction" -NotePropertyValue "IA1";
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "WarningAction";
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterType" -NotePropertyValue "System.String";
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterSets" -NotePropertyValue "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}";
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "IsDynamic" -NotePropertyValue "False";
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Aliases" -NotePropertyValue "ia";
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Attributes" -NotePropertyValue $null;
    $param2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SwitchParameter" -NotePropertyValue "False";

    $param3 = New-Object PsObject;
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ErrorAction" -NotePropertyValue "IA1";
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "ErrorAction";
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterType" -NotePropertyValue "System.String";
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterSets" -NotePropertyValue "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}";
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "IsDynamic" -NotePropertyValue "False";
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Aliases" -NotePropertyValue "ia";
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Attributes" -NotePropertyValue $null;
    $param3 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SwitchParameter" -NotePropertyValue "False";

    $psObjectTemp = New-Object PsObject;
    $psObjectTemp | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $param1.Name -NotePropertyValue $param1;
    $psObjectTemp | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $param2.Name -NotePropertyValue $param2;
    $psObjectTemp | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $param3.Name -NotePropertyValue $param3;

    $function1.Params = $psObjectTemp

#EndRegion / Step 1 (create object)


#Region Step 2 (update object)

    $param4 = New-Object PsObject;
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "InformationVariable" -NotePropertyValue "IA1";
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "InformationVariable";
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterType" -NotePropertyValue "System.String";
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterSets" -NotePropertyValue "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}";
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "IsDynamic" -NotePropertyValue "False";
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Aliases" -NotePropertyValue "ia";
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Attributes" -NotePropertyValue $null;
    $param4 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SwitchParameter" -NotePropertyValue "False";

    $param5 = New-Object PsObject;
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "WarningVariable" -NotePropertyValue "IA1";
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "WarningVariable";
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterType" -NotePropertyValue "System.String";
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterSets" -NotePropertyValue "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}";
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "IsDynamic" -NotePropertyValue "False";
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Aliases" -NotePropertyValue "ia";
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Attributes" -NotePropertyValue $null;
    $param5 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SwitchParameter" -NotePropertyValue "False";

    $param6 = New-Object PsObject;
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ErrorVariable" -NotePropertyValue "IA1";
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "ErrorVariable";
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterType" -NotePropertyValue "System.String";
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ParameterSets" -NotePropertyValue "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}";
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "IsDynamic" -NotePropertyValue "False";
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Aliases" -NotePropertyValue "ia";
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Attributes" -NotePropertyValue $null;
    $param6 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SwitchParameter" -NotePropertyValue "False";

    $psObjectTemp = New-Object PsObject;
    $psObjectTemp = $function1.Params;
    $psObjectTemp | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $param4.Name -NotePropertyValue $param4;
    $psObjectTemp | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $param5.Name -NotePropertyValue $param5;
    $psObjectTemp | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $param6.Name -NotePropertyValue $param6;
    
    $function1.Params = $psObjectTemp;

#EndRegion / Step 2 (update object)
```

[image: Step 1 results]
[image: Step 2 results]

**After using the accepted answer, I am happy to see this**

[image]

Comment: If you’re adding a new property to an *existing* object then ```Add-Member``` is the way to go, but there’s an easiesr way to initialise a new object using a hashtable - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-object-psobject-property-hashtable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify the code using [`[PSCustomObject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2#creating-a-pscustomobject) literals and [`Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Member?view=powershell-7.2#-notepropertymembers) to add multiple properties stored in a `hashtable` to an existing object. Also the temporary variable `$psObjectTemp` isn't really necessary.

```sh
#Region Step 1 (create object)

    $function1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = "Test1"
        Params = [PSCustomObject]@{
            InformationAction = [PSCustomObject]@{
                InformationAction = "IA1"
                Name = "InformationAction"
                ParameterType = "System.String"
                ParameterSets = "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}"
                IsDynamic = "False"
                Aliases = "ia"
                Attributes = $null
                SwitchParameter = "False"           
            }
            WarningAction = [PSCustomObject]@{
                <# TODO #>
            }
            ErrorAction = [PSCustomObject]@{
                <# TODO #>
            }
        }
    }


#EndRegion / Step 1 (create object)


#Region Step 2 (update object)

    $function1.Params | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{
        InformationVariable = [PSCustomObject]@{
            InformationVariable = "IA1"
            Name = "InformationVariable"
            ParameterType = "System.String"
            ParameterSets = "{[__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]}"
            IsDynamic = "False"
            Aliases = "ia"
            Attributes = $null
            SwitchParameter = "False"            
        }
        WarningVariable = [PSCustomObject]@{
            <# TODO #>            
        }
        ErrorVariable = [PSCustomObject]@{
            <# TODO #>
        }
    }

#EndRegion / Step 2 (update object)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another easy method using 'Select-Object'

The Implementation is faster and cleaner IMO.

```
$Row = "" | Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
$Row2 = "" | Select Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8
$Row2.Col6 = "Test"

$Row.Col1 = "Data1"
$Row.Col2 = 50
$Row.Col3 = $Row2
$Row.Col4 = $Row2.Col6

Col1  Col2 Col3                              Col4
----  ---- ----                              ----
Data1   50 @{Col5=; Col6=Test; Col7=; Col8=} Test
```

If later, you want to add columns(properties) you can do:

```
$Row = $Row | Select *,Col10
```

Comment: Although I accepted the other answer, this looks a little less intuitive but quicker once grasped and I will be trying to implement this on my test object and see how it goes. I have done this once before with a much less complex object and I like how simple it is.

Do you know what the difference with the result is with using `Select` vs `Select-Object` in this scenario? In the past, I believe I used `Select` only

Comment: `select` is just an alias of `Select-Object`